# Streamlit text_input or chat_input set dynamically

Tags: python, streamlit

Is there a way to set dynamic text on a text input or a chat input? Context is I am allowing users to say something on their microphones, transcribing audio to text and I want to place the transcribed text on the chat input or text input so they can interact with the app. Is this possible with text_input or chat_input? Or am I better off using another library?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's the best, but here is one way you can achieve this using the `session_state`:

```py
import streamlit as st

if not st.session_state.get("default_text"):
    st.session_state.default_text = "Hello world"

c = st.container()

btn = st.button("Change the text")
if btn:
    st.session_state.default_text = 'some text'

text = c.text_input("Text input", st.session_state.default_text)

st.write("You entered: ", text)
```

Several things to note here:

- We create an empty container so that the creation of the `text_input` happens after the button, but we could have just put the button above instead.
- If the new text is the same as the last one, it will not be updated. because the state is kept as it is in the `text_input`.

One way to fix the latter is to use a different string, for instance:

```py
import streamlit as st

if not st.session_state.get("default_text"):
    st.session_state.default_text = "Hello world"

c = st.container()

btn = st.button("Change the text")
if btn:
    new_text = 'some text'

    # This is a hack to force the session state to change
    if st.session_state.default_text == new_text:
        new_text = 'some text '

    st.session_state.default_text = new_text

text = c.text_input("Text input", st.session_state.default_text)

st.write("You entered: ", text)
```

But I guess for your use case you will not need to care about exact duplicates.